# Large-value ceramic caps  in small packages?

Tags: capacitor

I'm looking at some capacitors, namely ceramic, 10µF 50V caps. [Here are the search results](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=500006+1000225&Ntk=gensearch_001&Ntt=10u+50V&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial) on Farnell UK.

Most are in big packages, 2220 or some form of stacked capacitor. But then there are the occasional X7R and X5R caps in 1206 and 1210 packages, like this one: [GRM31CR61H106KA12L](http://uk.farnell.com/murata/grm31cr61h106ka12l/capacitor-1206-10uf-50v/dp/1845762). It seems too good to be true, it's half the size of others and very low cost. It's not available yet, otherwise I would have bought some and tested them.

Any opinions? Has anyone tried these?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is very likely that the 1206 ceramic cap and the large stacked ceramic cap differ greatly in one very important characteristic.

ESR

The larger cap can probably handle much larger surge and RMS currents, and likely has significantly lower ESR.

Remember, there is more to a cap than voltage and number of uF. If you're putting the cap in a big DC-DC that dumps 10A into the cap every switching cycle, and the 1206 cap has an ESR of .05 Ω, it'll get really hot and fail in a hurry.

The big stacked ceramics are typically used in extreme-duty power supplies, where a tantalum or electrolytic cannot handle the conditions.

Comment: I can't find the ESR rating for those caps anywhere. The datasheet is the same for a million other types.

Comment: The ESR is rated using graphs. It's ESR vs Frequency. I found it on both links provided in the question, and the bigger cap is indeed lower ESR.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there are  some major leadtime issues on the denser ceramics at the moment, so the latest dielectrics seem to include some unobtanium.

Answer (score 1):

The part you listed is apparently X5R, not X7R, and yes, ceramic caps have become incredible in the last few years.

Comment: Yeah I know... but check out the other results, there are only a few 1206 packages, most are 2220 or stacked, and these are often cheaper than the bigger ones. These are great caps.

Answer (score 1):

Some capacitors exhibit capacitance which varies with voltage.  As a physical analogy, a "perfect" capacitor will behave as a cylinder filled with liquid (adding a particular volume of liquid will increase the pressure, always at the same rate) while some caps behave more like a point-up code (the amount of liquid required for each unit increase in pressure decreases as the cap fills up).  Note that beyond the fact that one may have to use a higher-rated cap to get the capacitance one wants at the actual working voltage, there's another consequence of this behavior for intermittently-powered devices in battery-operated systems: whereas a normal cap will take 9/16 as much energy to charge to 3 volts as to charge to 4 volts, a cap with whose capacitance decreases with voltage will require more energy for the lower-voltage part of the charge.  If a cap will be charged to 4 volts and needs to supply a certain amount of energy before the voltage drops to 3 volts, the latter cap will effectively waste more energy each time it's switched on.

What would be ideal would be if someone could construct a cap which had the opposite sort of behavior--something electrically equivalent to a cap wired in series with a battery (so that capacitance would be maximized at voltages near the battery voltage).  There would be no net current flow into or out of the battery, but shifting the maximum-capacitance voltage would allow intermittently-powered devices to work more efficiently.  I wonder if using different metals for the anode and cathode of a cap would have such an effect?

Answer (score 0):

Look at them all its to do with the tolerances the cheap ones have a much higher tolerance than the more expensive ones.

Comment: Capacitance Tolerance: ±10% plus Temperature Coefficient: ±15%, for a capacitor that's pretty good...